# Desabilitar datas anteriores ao dia atual no DateTimePicker?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime

É possível no `DateTimePicker`, desabilitar os dias anteriores ao dia atual?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode fazer isto adicionando as datas que deseja em [`MinDate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.mindate(v=vs.110).aspx) e [`MaxDate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.maxdate(v=vs.110).aspx), obviamente o mínimo pode ser a menor data válida e o máximo o dia de ontem. Algo assim:

```
this.dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
this.dateTimePicker1.MinDate = DateTimePicker.MinimumDateTime;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/Before.cs).

A pergunta mudou no meio do caminho mas a resposta permanece a mesma, já que muda o controle mas as propriedades [`MinDate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate(v=vs.110).aspx) e [`MaxDate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maxdate.aspx) são idênticas.

Comment: Perfeito bigown. Eu havia colocado o monthCalendar, depois corrigi para DataTimePicker, mas mesmo assim funcionou seu código. Porém quando clicamos no DataTimePicker, a data anterior ao dia atual aparecem, sumindo só depois que selecionamos uma data. É possível que não apareça ao clicar no DataTimePicker?

Comment: Eu acredito que não a não ser criando um controle próprio, pelo menos não achei nada que indicasse isto.

Comment: Certo. Mesmo assim sua dica funcionou bigown. Ao selecionar uma data anterior a data atual, ele coloca a data atual e os dias anteriores somem.

Obrigado